# Why can't I add top margin to my <a> tag when I am using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was creating a navigation bar while using bootstrap framework.

My html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div  class="navbar-landing">
            <a href="www.bloomboard.com"><b>BB</b> COLLAB</a>
        </div>
      </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,900");

.container-fluid{
    padding:0;
}
.navbar-landing{
    background-color:#FD761F;
    height:60px;
    width:180px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.navbar-landing a{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:60px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

but the top margin does not work. It always look like this
[image]

So frustrated! Thank you for your help!

Comment: That link won't work as you intended unless you add `http://` or `//`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because by default, links are inline elements and inline elements don't have top/bottom margins. Change the link to an inline-block element instead.

```
.navbar-landing a{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:60px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/lV9sw57c53)**

(and here's a bonus [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties) to the spec if you're interested, "vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements.")

Comment: I was going to make the same answer. A good article explaining this is http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

Answer (score 1):

You need to display the link as a block (or inline-block if you wish to keep more than one link at the same height). Add the display property in the link css, like this:

```
.navbar-landing a {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:60px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution in my case.

My case: The `a` tag needs to be `inline` and shouldn't change its block type. But I need margin-top/bottom.

Solution: Add pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` to the `a` tag.

```css
    a::before{
     content: '';
     height: 30px; /*This is the margin top*/
     display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I wrap the links in `<p>` tags.

For example change this:

```
<a href="www.example.com">Link 1</a>
<a href="www.example.com">Link 2</a>
<a href="www.example.com">Link 3</a>
```

to this:

```
<p><a href="www.example.com">Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href="www.example.com">Link 2</a></p>
<p><a href="www.example.com">Link 3</a></p>
```

Then you can add whatever classes you like to the p tag. For example `<p class="mb-4">`.