# Bootstrap 4 - Why spacing margin class mt-3 doesn't work on <a> tag?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the spacing class mt-3 on some links to add a margin top in a page where is loaded bootstrap 4.

But the class produce no effect, I don't get any margin top.

```
<div class="row py-1 border-bottom">
     <div class="col-6">
          Menu voice 2
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
         <a href="#" class="bg-success text-white p-1 mt-3">it</a>
         <a href="#" class="bg-success text-white p-1 mt-3">en</a>
         <a href="#" class="bg-success text-white p-1 mt-3">fr</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davideoz/L92usqmg/10/) you can see the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a>` tags are inline elements, so they have no margin. You can either change the CSS to `a {display: inline-block;}`, or use the [display utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) class `d-inline-block` in Bootstrap 4:

```
<a href="#" class="bg-success text-white d-inline-block p-1 mt-3">it</a>
```

Comment: I prefer the solution that use the display utility bootstrap 4 class

Answer (score 0):

This is because links are inline elements, you can add `a {display: inline-block}` to see the margin on your links

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution that worked for me was to wrap the `<a>` tags in `<p>` tags, then apply bootstrap margins/formatting to the p tag.

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74935547/5783745).

Answer (score -2):

Inline elements like `<a>` tags do not support margin and padding. Convert it to a block element first to use `mt` or `mb` in the element.